# middleware function not being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

i have this middleware function that supposed to create new product doc into the database:

```
exports.postAddProduct = (req, res, next)
```

the function is used in this route:

```
router.post(
  '/add-product',
  productValidation.addProductValidation,//(a middleware function that validate user input)
  isAuth,//(a middleware function that validate the user is logged in
  adminController.postAddProduct
);
```

the request is triggerd by an ejs form.
but still the middleware is not being called.
i will appreciate any help :)

Comment: Add some debug messages, have you tried it with curl/postman? What are the response?

Answer (score 1):

i can only assume in this case :

- An error is triggered during `productValidation.addProductValidation` or `isAuth`, the code would stop and throw a error(or be send to the error handling middleware)
- you forgot to add `next()` at the end of of three `middlewares`, it's easy to notice if you inspect the page using `F12` and look inside the `network` tab for the request that it's being called when the form is submited

Comment: hi thank you for your help, apperently ihad an error 'Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory' but i didnt got it becuse of the error middleware